# Why the Hubble parameter that is proportional to dark energy is squared in the Friedmann's equation?

Tags: cosmology, dark-energy, cosmological-constant

I'm studying Alexander Friedmann's equation about the Hubble parameter and, thus, the time dependence of the cosmic scale factor varies as the matter density, ρ, and as the dark energy, Λ as shown in the picture:
[image]

Comment: To further explain, I wonder why the Hubble parameter and rate of cosmic scale factor are both squared in this equation. Why they are not square-rooted to look simpler? Sorry if that's a stupid question.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you are asking why the convention for writing down the Friedmann equation is what it is?

Comment: Yes. Especially, why leaving both sides squared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has a positive and a negative solution, the positive is for an expanding big bang universe and the negative for a collapsing big crunch universe, since the physics is time reversible both solutions are valid solutions which depend on the initial conditions.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!